# Python: Reproducing MemoryError on OSX Mavericks

Tags: python, macos, out-of-memory, osx-mavericks

I'm using macbook pro with OSX for the development, but my scripts are executed on Linux servers with much smaller RAM available. Sometimes I catch 'MemoryError' on the server, and I want to debug the script on my local machine.

How can I limit memory for my python script on OSX?

I've seen the solution with using ulimit for linux-based systems:

```
ulimit -v 500000
```

but it seemed that it does not work on OSX Mavericks: 'memory limitations' are set correctly as verified by

```
ulimit -a
```

but the script takes all the memory it needs (it is seen in Activity Monitor).

Answer (score 0):

Since OS X is BSD and not Linux, this is an area where they differ. To limit a process you will have to use `launchctl limit`. The [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) has a list of all the options.